# Swift DateFormatter date from string fails where NSDateFormatter used to work

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

I have a date string : "2017-09-27T13:03:47.86+00:00" and the dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZZ" used to work with NSDateFormatter but returns nil with DateFormatter.date(string: )

any ideas what might work with swift DateFormatter?

Comment: Well, you should start with fixing the format. Do you see the number of millisecond digits you expect and the actual number of them?

Comment: Write your dateString above your date format, does it seem correct?  Why so many "S"? Why so many "Z" ? What does the spec says: how many, which letter vs expect: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns ?

Comment: @Larme The `ZZZZZ` format is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The format string is supposed to work if you set the locale to `en_US_POSIX`, however 2 `S` are sufficient

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZZZZZ"
```

Nevertheless I recommend to use dedicated `ISO8601DateFormatter`

```
let dateString = "2017-09-27T13:03:47.86+00:00"
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Comment: Dateformatter was too slow for me. I didn't know about this ISO8601 version. It works as a great alternative.